# Sampling None-size tensor from distribution in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

The following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tfd = tf.contrib.distributions

mean = [0.0, 0.0]
scale = [1.0, 1.0]

dist = tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=mean, scale_diag=scale)
samp = dist.sample([None])
```

Gives the error:

```
TypeError: Expected int32, got None of type '_Message' instead.
```

But generates n samples from the distribution if None is replaced with an integer n.  Is there any way to get an unknown number of samples from the distribution?

EDIT:  The original question may be badly phrased; I want to sample a tensor of shape (None, ...) to combine with other tensors of this shape.  Clearly somewhere in there an input is needed to fix the size at runtime.

Comment: How will it know how many samples to return if _you_ don't know how many samples you want?

Comment: I'd like the number of samples to be determined at runtime; by for example, pattern-matching with the size of some other input for a placeholder tensor (i.e. a tensor of shape (None, ...)).  I understand I might need to pass in such a tensor to the sampling process somehow, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: `samp = dist.sample(some_other_tensor.shape)`

Comment: In the use case I tried for this (taking an existing placeholder of shape (None, 4) and then selecting the first row to get one of shape (None,)), this resulted in the error: 

    `ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (?,)`

This does suggest part of my problem understanding was thinking that "shapes" are "tuples of None/integers" were the same thing, and that shapes are instead objects that count as 1d/0d tensors, but may be distinct from any constant 1d/0d tensor of None/integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
num_samples = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=())
sampl = dist.sample(num_samples)
```

and then feed in the number of samples. Likewise, if you have a scalar tensor representing the number of samples, you can pass that in.

Comment: This worked.  I end up pulling num_samples from another feed to a placeholder; is there a way to just use that placeholder directly without having to have a separate placeholder for its length?

Comment: You could use `tf.shape(other_placeholder)[0]`, which would use as the number of samples the elements in the first dimension of the shape of other_placeholder. 

Note that other_placeholder.shape may or may not work since the static shape is unknown.